# php remove duplicate except original

Tags: php

this is my code

```
   <?php 

    $string = 'this
    this 
    good 
    good 
    hahah';

    $rows = explode("\n",$string);
    $unwanted = 'this|good';
    $cleanArray= preg_grep("/$unwanted/i",$rows,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
    $cleanString=implode("\n",$cleanArray);
    print_r ( $cleanString );

?>
```

display

```
hahah
```

i want like this

```
this 
good 
hahah
```

i want to keep one...
please help me, thanks guys

Comment: Just to clarify - do you only want the words in `$unwanted` removed and not just duplicates?

Comment: if line contains xxxx delete that line, not just duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code resorts to checking each line to see if it matches your `$unwanted` string, but it also creates an array of strings it has already encountered so it checks if it has previously been encountered ( using `in_array()`).  If it matches and has been encountered before it uses `unset()` in the original `$rows` to remove the line...

```
$string = 'this
    this
    good
   good
    hahah';

$rows = explode("\n",$string);
$unwanted = 'this|good';
$matched = [];
foreach ( $rows as $line => $row )   {
    if ( preg_match("/$unwanted/i",$row, $matches))  {
        if ( in_array(trim($matches[0]), $matched) === true )    {
            unset($rows[$line]);
        }
        $matched[] = $matches[0];
    }
}
$cleanString=implode("\n",$rows);
print_r ( $cleanString );
```

Comment: hello my message is not clear, can you do if line contains good delete that line sir e.g. good one <<< No matter what after "good" is... delete all line except one

Comment: `$matched = [];` throws a syntax error if PHP is not version 5.5+

Comment: I've updated the code - it just stores anything that matches and so should work

Comment: If I do `$unwanted = 'this|good|xxxxx';` and add 'xxxxx' to the list 'xxxxx' does not get removed. Isn

Comment: @JayBlanchard when setting `$unwanted = 'this|good|xxxxx';` - you have to add `xxxxx` twice (the remove last duplicate condition).

Comment: Yeah, I just tested down @NigelRen and found that too.

Comment: I thought the 'xxxxx' question was not only about duplicates based on this comment under my answer *"if line contains xxxx delete that line, not just duplicates "*

Comment: Nigel Ren your updated code is working perfectly! thank you everyone for your time

Comment: @dmpower007 it doesn't do what you asked earlier which is *"if line contains xxxx delete that line, **not just duplicates** "*

Comment: @JayBlanchard, do you think they are using *xxxx* to mean the value and not just the literal.  So if the line is `this one` and a later line has `not this one` then the second should be deleted as it contains the word `this` but isn't exactly the same.

Comment: That seems like what the OP is asking, no? Isn't that what you questioned me on?

Comment: my english not good sir.. so i don't know how to explain what i want exactly.. sorry again..

Comment: @NigelRen look at this - your code, different conditions. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1354e360eacf349d1385d22c9ca6d7069e02613e

Comment: @JayBlanchard, it ONLY applies as `this` is one of the words to match.  In the code you point to - there is not duplicate of *xxxxx* so it shouldn't be removed, add another one and the second one will be removed.

Comment: But I put 'xxxxx' in `$unwanted` to satisfy "if line contains xxxx delete that line, not just duplicates "

Comment: They mean that the line should be matched if the line *contains* xxxx - so a line with *xxxx hehe* (as in the comment to the first answer) as well as *xxxx*, *hehe xxxx*.

Comment: I'll accept what you're saying (and have been the lone UV on your answer) but if I were to take what the OP is saying literally that could still go either way, *lines* or *words*

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $string = 'this
    this 
    good
    yyyy
    good
    xxxx
    hahah';

    print_r(
       implode("\n", 
          array_diff(array_unique(
             array_map(function($v) { return trim($v);}, explode("\n",$string))
          )
       ,array('xxxx', 'yyyy')))
    );

?>
```

**output**:

```
this
good
hahah
```

Refer: https://ideone.com/Eo0MIM

Comment: if line contains xxxx delete that line, can you help me ronak

Comment: that is again can be achieved using array_diff 

https://ideone.com/0DlKj9

Comment: can't delete "xxxx 2" , if line contains "xxxx" delete that line e.g. "xxxx hehe"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code to get result:

```
$result = array_unique(explode("\n",str_replace(" ", "", $string)));
print_r ($result);
```

If you want more control over your data, use this code

```
$rows = explode("\n", $string);
$words = [];
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row = trim($row);
    $words[$row] = true;
}

foreach($words as $word => $tmp) {
    echo $word . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c001a58d8de247219bf7ac58d98824b2c891805a) is one way you could do this:

```
$string = 'this
    this 
    good 
    good 
    hahah';

preg_match_all('/([a-z])+/', $string, $matches);
$string = implode("\n",array_unique($matches[0]));
echo $string;
```

Comment: if line contains xxxx delete that line, not just duplicates

Comment: Now you're changing the rules. That's a new question.

Comment: Not sure if it is - they have `$unwanted = 'this|good';` in the question, which is why I asked for clarification as these happen to be the only duplicate values.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that @NigelRen, but the title says *"remove duplicate"*

Answer (score 0):

You can use php inbuilt `array_unique` function

```php
<?php
   $string = 'this
this
good
good
haha';

    $rows = explode("\n",$string);
    $cleanArray = array_unique($rows);
    $cleanString=implode("\n",$cleanArray);
print_r ( $cleanString );

//result is this good haha
```